# Zombies/Robots, Can you combine they're coming to get you and zapbot?

Tags: smash-up

I was playing zombies/robots and near the end game had all of my zapbots in the discard pile. If I use "they're coming to get you" (you may play a minion on this base from your discard pile instead of your hand) can I use zapbot's ability (play another minion of power 2 or less) to play all of my remaining zapbots from the discard pile?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No, only one Zapbot can come from the discard pile.**

While the text *is* unclear, AEG has issued an official ruling on BoardGameGeek, [here](https://boardgamegeek.com/article/11915821#11915821).

> It only lets you play a single minion that way, *not whenever* you play a minion.

That is, you can make one minion play each turn on the base with "They're Coming to Get You" from the discard pile.

However, playing a Zapbot from your discard still triggers its ability, which would allow you to play additional minions from your hand.

Comment: Also Zombies/Robots is so obscenely powerful anyway :P We had to ban it in our group after 3 players working together couldn't stop the Zombot player over the whole game.